# Pgfplot label of y-axis tick mark

Tags: pgfplots

I've gotten this far, but I can't go any further on my own. I have this plot:

[image]

which was generated using this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
  ymin=0, ymax=0.1, ytick={0,0.083}, ylabel=$f(x)$,
  xmin=5, xmax=19, xtick={5, 6, 7, 8, 17, 18}, xlabel=$x$,
  domain=-pi:pi,samples=101, % added
]
    \addplot[domain=6:8,gray,name path=A] {0.083}; % actual curve

    \addplot[draw=none,name path=B,domain=6:8] {0}; 

    \addplot[domain=6:18,gray,name path=fullA]{0.083}; %total uniform area
    \addplot[draw=none,name path=fullb,domain=6:18]{0};

\addplot[gray] fill between[of=A and B,soft clip={domain=6:8}]; %filling

coordinates {

    (6, 0)
    (6, 0.083)
    (8, 0)
    (8, 0.083)
    (18, 0)
    (18, 0.083)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like:

1) the label of the tick mark associated with 0.083 to instead read 1/12

2) a vertical gray line from (18,0) to (18, 0.083) (the plot should look like a rectangle within a rectangle)

3) the labels x and f(x) on the outside of the axes instead of inside (below the tick marks for x; on the left of the tick marks for y).

How can I do these things?

Comment: Part 3) solved: `axis x line=bottom, axis y line=left`, instead of axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `pgf` does have the option of printing numbers as fractions, so you can do `yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/frac denom=12,/pgf/number format/frac}` (thanks to  Schrödinger's cat for mentioning the first of those). Or you can do it manually with   `yticklabels={$0$,$\frac{1}{12}$}`
2. Of the multiple ways of doing that, you can actually just add `-- (18,0)` at the end of the `\addplot` which draws the horizontal line.

(Note by the way that you can actually input 1/12 directly instead of 0.083, as in the example below.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line=bottom, axis y line=left,
  ymin=0, ymax=0.1, ytick={0,1/12}, ylabel=$f(x)$,
  xmin=5, xmax=19, xtick={5, 6, 7, 8, 17, 18}, xlabel=$x$,
  domain=-pi:pi,samples=101, % added
  yticklabel style={
     /pgf/number format/frac denom=12,
     /pgf/number format/frac
  } % automatic formatting
  %yticklabels={$0$,$\frac{1}{12}$} %  or do it manually instead
]
    \addplot[domain=6:8,gray,name path=A] {1/12}; % actual curve

    \addplot[draw=none,name path=B,domain=6:8] {0}; 

    \addplot[domain=6:18,gray,name path=fullA]{1/12} -- (18,0); %total uniform area
    \addplot[draw=none,name path=fullb,domain=6:18]{0};

\addplot[gray] fill between[of=A and B,soft clip={domain=6:8}]; %filling
coordinates {
    (6, 0)
    (6, 1/12)
    (8, 0)
    (8, 1/12)
    (18, 0)
    (18, 1/12)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks, didn't read that far in the manual, so hadn't seen the frac denom setting.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Perhaps badly phrased, what I meant was: "to the addplot which draws the horizontal line, add ..."